# Firebase onSnapshot returns only the changed item

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first post on stackoverflow, and I'm looking for some help because I've been scratching my head at this for awhile now.

I am currently developing a web application with Firebase and I am using the `onSnapshot` method. Currently, I'm returning a list of users from my db
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5UVV.png).
And the following is my function that populates the UI.

```
db.collectionGroup('items').where("userid", "==", user.id).orderBy('date', "desc").limit(80).onSnapshot(snapshot => {

 snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    if (change.type === 'added') {
       setupLedger(snapshot.docs, doc.id)
    }    
    if (change.type === 'modified') {
       setupLedger(snapshot.docs, doc.id)
    } 
    if (change.type === 'removed') {
       deleteLedger(user, doc.id);
    }
 });
});
```

On page load, I get all my necessary data with the `type: "added"`
([see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoqgB.png))

My issue occurs when I click on `EDIT` (i.e. modify), it only returns the modified entry and updates the modified entry ([see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtdEV.png)). But if I click on `EDIT` on another field, it will display the previous entry, not the current one ([see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC0D6.png)). How would I be able to change my method so I can get all the entries including the modified one? Essentially, I'd like to update only the current item, once it updates, I would like to return the array (with the modified item).

(side note: If I refresh the page, the array is returned with modified item and everything works as expected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the docs affected by your query (whether they are modified or not), can be accessed via `snapshot.docs` while extra info about the changed docs are accessed through `snapshot.docChanges()`. So, consider changing your code to something like this:

```js
db.collectionGroup('items').where("userid", "==", user.id).orderBy('date', "desc").limit(80).onSnapshot(snapshot => {

  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jay; Correct me if I'm wrong but I think I get it, docChanges() only returns the modified element, whereas docs actually gets all elements from document.

Comment: Yes, and at first time all returned documents are marked as "added" and so, are included in both `docs` and `docChanges()`